# CSS: Оставить calc или лучше использовать min-aspect-ratio?

Tags: css

Возникла задача написать страницу без скролла. Блок контента должен сохранять пропорции и не вылезать из экрана. Написал через calc+min+max. **Но не уверен по поводу мобильных устройств**. На htmlbook вообще указано, что android и ios calc не поддерживают. Так что думаю, не переписать ли через min-aspect-ratio.

Так как сам не часто использовал calc и min-aspect-ratio и всех подводных камней не знаю, то хотел узнать у более опытных программистов, какие проблемы могут возникнуть с calc и насколько они актуальны.

Comment: А где вы прочитали, что мобилки не поддерживают `calc`? Не поддерживается разве что в `opera mini`

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо! Прочитал на htmlbook на странице calc. Там два красных крестика под Android и iOS.

Comment: Смотрите на [can i use](https://caniuse.com/?search=calc) поддержку.